# Android SeekBarChangeListener and TouchListener No Events

Tags: android, input

I'm having an issue with button click events and seekbar events not firing. When I drag on my seekbar, the slider changes position visually but there's no event being fired in my `OnSeekBarChangedListener`. I also have an `ImageButton` that should receive click events but it does not fire either. The MyView at the bottom here handles touch events properly. It holds a `GLSurfaceView` that I can pan around and pinch-zoom on. What could be causing the events to not fire?

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tec_root">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_star"
        android:contentDescription="@string/star_description"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/star_empty"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_plot"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/button_star"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/button_star"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/button_star"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/button_star"
        android:id="@+id/seekbar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here are the listeners:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
    starred = prefs.getBoolean("starred", false);

    final ImageButton starButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_star);
    starButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, (starred ? R.drawable.star_filled :
            R.drawable.star_empty)));

    starButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            starred = !starred;

            prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
            prefsEditor.putBoolean("starred", starred);
            prefsEditor.apply();

            starButton.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(),
                    (starred ? R.drawable.star_filled : R.drawable.star_empty)));
        }
    });

    ((SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar)).setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            Log.e("TEST", "Seekbar onProgressChanged called");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Seekbar fired", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // respond to update
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    MyView myView = new MyView(this, points, false);
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_plot)).addView(myView);
}
```

Comment: Could you override onTouchEvent in the seekbar and post the log? From the documentation and the source code for a SeekBar it looks like views left / right of it that are focusable could "steal" touch events, resulting in a reDraw but not in a progress update notification.

Comment: Well it's started working out of the blue for some reason. I changed the class a bit but don't recall changing anything dealing with the logic of that `SeekBar`.

Comment: Try to initiate the seekbar before setting the Listener.

Comment: can you post your `MyView`? I saw your code, no problem but your `GlSurfaceView`. You should post it in order to get help.

Comment: your code is working and fired the toast when i checked but i removed the your this code  MyView myView = new MyView(this, points, false);
    ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_plot)).addView(myView);  so could you post the this code and related to it code so we can help you out

Comment: This is just a guess bt try removing the override methods in each listner,then u will be prompted to implement the methods then u paste ur code in the listner and try.

Answer (score 3):

try this, replace LinearLayout with FrameLayout, it's not best at perfomance but works well

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tec_root"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekbar"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ABABAB"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:progress="50" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_star"
                android:layout_width="32dp"
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:contentDescription="@string/star_description"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/star_empty" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/view_plot"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"      
            />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to this:

```
MyView myView = new MyView(this, points, false);
    myView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view_plot)).addView(myView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be reproduced by removing the GLSurfaceView?

If so, changing `SurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop` might help.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderOnTop(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

there may be issue of layout design so please rearrange the components of ui.
seekbar is over imagebutton so android platform is not able to detect touch event.

set layout_below in seekbar

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason for this could be touch handling in custom MyView. We have to be very careful about return value of onTouchEvent() function. Try returning "true" from your onTouchEvent() if you are consuming event else return "false".